# sed line range, all but the last line

Tags: sed

You can specify a range of lines to operate on. For example, to operate on all lines, (which is of course the default):

```
sed -e "1,$ s/a/b/"
```

But I need to operate on all but the last line. You apparently can't use arithmetic expressions:

```
sed -e "1,$-1 s/a/b/"
```

(I am using cygwin in this case, if it makes a difference)

Answer (score 64, accepted):

```
sed -e "$ ! s/a/b/"
```

This will match every line but the last. Confirmed with a quick test!

Comment: To explain what happens here: `$` selects the last line. `!` then negates that line range, to select every line _except_ the last line. The search-replace is then performed over the resulting line range.

Comment: This did work for me if you have an empty line in the lines block

Answer (score 19):

This command works, too

```
sed '$d'
```

Comment: What if he wants the last line printed out?

Answer (score 3):

I know it is not `sed`, but I feel that `head` gets the easiest and most flexible way:

```
head -n -1 the-file
```

Use -2, -3... instead of -1, to retrieve all but the last two lines, etc.

Comment: this is what i usually do, but `head(1)` on mac cannot handle negative arguments

Comment: Some MacOS shells don't support the "-1"

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could hack it with something like this:

```
sed -e "1,$(($(cat the-file | wc -l) - 1))s/a/b/"
```

Or, you could use `tail` instead:

```
(tail +1 the-file) | sed -e s/a/b/; tail -1 the-file
```

Answer (score -1):

In a more general sense, this issue requires you to edit a stream by specifying a range with one of the range limits being an offset from the end-of-file. The following example shows how to do this. In this example I am printing out all the lines of a file, beginning with the 5th line from the last line, and ending with the last line. In your case, you can set `OFFSET = -1`instead of `OFFSET = -5`.

```
(( OFFSET = -5 )); (( N1 = $(cat pgen.c | wc -l) + OFFSET )); sed -n "$N1,\$p" thefile
```

This command can be entered in one line.

Comment: Alejandro, this answer should be deleted, and the introductory text moved to your replacement answer.