# SED: Operate on Last seven lines regardless of file length

Tags: sed

I would like to operate on the last 7 lines of a file with sed regardless of the filelength.

According to a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/947404/530634) this type of range won't work: `$-6,$ {..commands..}`

What is the equivalent that will?

Comment: (a) You can't - `sed` is the wrong tool for the job.  (b) If you're perverse enough to insist, you can explore the hold space and the pattern space and try to keep just seven lines in the hold space (or maybe 6) and then process the hold space when the pattern space is for the last line.  But that is fiendishly hard - I really wouldn't bother (and I've done scary things with `sed`, but there comes a point at which you choose the correct tool for the job).

Answer (score 2):

Pipe the output of [tail -7](http://lowfatlinux.com/linux-head-tail.html) into sed.

```
tail -7 test.txt | sed -e "s/e/WWW/"
```

More info on Pipes [here.](http://www.december.com/unix/tutor/pipesfilters.html)

Comment: Brian, I can't use this solution because I'm using need to use this range together with other ranges (for example I need to process the first six and last seven lines of the same file and return the processed file.

Comment: In that case, I'd recommend using a python or perl script to process the file.  (I'm partial to python...) It'll probably be easier to maintain.

Answer (score 1):

You could just switch from sed(1) to ed(1), the commands are about the same. In this case, the command *is* the same, except with no limitations on address range.

```
$ cat > fl7.ed
ed - $1 << \eof
1,7s/$/ (one of the first seven lines)/
$-6,$s/$/ (one of the last seven lines)/
w
q
eof
$ sh fl7.ed yourfile
```

Comment: +1: The only snag here is when the input to be processed comes from a pipe, but using `ed` is sometimes correct.  After all, `ed` is 'the standard text editor' (according to the 7th Edition manual).

Comment: If the file is shorter than 13 lines, some will be tagged twice.

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -lne 'END{print join$\,@a,"-",@b}push@a,$_ if@a<6;push@b,$_;shift@b if@b>7'
```

In the `END{}` block you can do whatever is required; `@a` contains the first 6, `@b` the last 7 lines as requested.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
sed '1{N;N;N;N;N};N;$s/foo/bar/g;P;D' inputfile
```

Explanation:

- `1{N;N;N;N;N}` - when the first line is read, load the pattern space with five more lines (total: 6 at this point)
- `N` - append another line
- `$s/foo/bar/g` - when the last line is read, perform some operation on the entire contents of pattern space (the last seven lines of the file). Operations can be more complex than shown here
- `P` - print the test before the first newline in pattern space
- `D` - delete the text just printed and loop to the beginning of the script (the "append another line" step - the first instruction is skipped since it only applies to the first line in the file)

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
sed ':a;1,6{$!N;ba};${s/foo/bar/g;q};N;D' file
```

Explanation:

- Create a loop label. `:a`
- Gather lines 1 to 6 in the pattern space (PS). `1,6{$!N;ba}`
- If it's the last line, process the PS and quit, therefore printing out the last seven lines. `${s/foo/bar/g;q}`
- If it's not the last line, append the next line to the PS. `N`
- Delete upto the first newline and begin a new cycle without reading a new line. `D`