# Search and replace all but the last line in sed?

Tags: file, replace, sed

I know if you specify `:1,$-1s/stuff/noun/g` in vim you can run a search and replace on the entire file, excluding the last line.

Is there a syntax that can specify that you want to run a search and replace on all but the very last line in the file in `sed`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed -e '$q' -e 's/stuff/noun/g' file
```

Quit after printing the last line; otherwise, do the substitution.

See also [`sed` line range all but the last line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/947404/sed-line-range-all-but-the-last-line); it would recommend:

```
sed '$! s/stuff/noun/g' file
```